# How to remove a single letter word in a string by javascript?

Tags: javascript

My original string = `A abc, B xyz, C mlk ooo`

How can I remove single letter of each element: `A  B C`?

Expected Output = `abc, xyz, mlk ooo`

Comment: standalone letters commonly appear in human readable text, i.e., "a", "i". Are you sure that, for example, stripping out the text before the first space is not a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/9473764) to replace a single letter (indicated by a letter with a word-break `\b` on either side of it) followed by some number of spaces with nothing:

```js
const str = "A abc, B xyz, C mlk ooo"

const output = str.replace(/\b[a-z]\b\s*/ig, '', str)

console.log(output)
```

[Regex demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/z1oQSk/1)

Comment: Nice anwser,but I haven't see any `()` in your regex expression,could you explain a bit,please?

Comment: @lucumt why do you think there should be any `()`?

Comment: ,I am not very good at regex,I just think need to get the result by group

Comment: @lucumt not in this case, I am replacing the entire match (a letter followed by 0 or more spaces) with nothing. So I don't need any groups.

Comment: @Nick Thank you. I use some special font and this ouput wrong. Please see screenshot: https://ibb.co/8PyyK02. How can fix for my font. Eg string = "T Trâm, S - Sơn, T Tiên".  Thank you

Comment: @SHDT you should be able to use `str.replace(/\b\p{L}\b\s*/igu, '', str)`

Comment: @Nick thank you. Input string = "= "T Trâm, S - Sơn, T Tiên". But this output is wrong:  "Tr, - , Ti" . Please see: https://ibb.co/Srvtv4j . Correct output should be = "Trâm,  Sơn, Tiên" .

Comment: @SHDT sorry, forgot that `\b` doesn't work with unicode letters. `/(?<!\p{L})\p{L}(?!\p{L})\s*/igu` should work

Comment: @SHDT no worries - I'm glad that worked for you